# Need formula for 2 columns (B & F) the whole column needs the formula

Tags: excel-formula

I need if anything in column `"B" = 1129826`, then if true column "F" needs to be > 5000. Then I will make the font bold red.

```
="$B:$B =""1129826"",True"
```

I wasn't sure where to go from here or if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: you want conditional formatting formula?

Comment: Yes I do, I need the cell in column "F" to turn red if < 5000, but only if the cell in Column "B" is = 1129826

Comment: `=AND($B1=1129826,$F1>5000)` and apply to the full column in F.

Comment: isn't $B1 only going to do just that cell? same with F1? Would I do $B:$B and same with "F"

Comment: No, you would apply the conditional formatting to the entire column and use the formula as is.  Excel will iterate the relative reference.

Comment: This is what I entered into Column "F" =AND($B1=1129826,$F1<5000) and this is what I put into Column "J" =AND($B1=1129826,$J1<5000), for some reason it is not  working now. It worked when I first put it in now nothing.

Comment: I put some code into a code section. Also tried to improve some code formatting. Hope that this has helped in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you are looking for in the Conditional Format, highlighting both `B` and `F` Columns:

`=AND($B1=1129826,$F1>5000)`

Which should give the result of:
[image: Conditional Format Answer]

Hopefully this is what you are looking for!